# saving always adds artefacts to my images that photoshop doesn't

Tags: c#, image, compression, image-compression, lossy-compression

There's lots of posts on here about code to resize images down, but with all of them I get this artefact problem that I don't get when doing it manually in photoshop.

Is there something MORE I can do to fix this? I notice that when exporting bitmap from Photoshop I can make the export "**progressive**", is there something similar that might help in C#?

Photoshop's downscaling of 1080p to 480p:

[image: a fairly smooth downscale]

Everything from SO's resizing of 1080p to 480p:

[image: Jagged artefacts on the collar]

The rest of the image is similar but the collar here is a good example of the noise I'm getting with my code.

My current function:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
        {

                
                var destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                var destImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);

                destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

                using (var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
                {
                    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                    using (var wrapMode = new System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes())
                    {
                        wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                        graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                    }
                }

                return destImage;

        }
```

Here's the original image in 1920x1080 for reference:
[image: a screenshot at 1080p]

Comment: Are you sure that this is not due to jpeg compression artifacts? That is the way your second image looks to me at least. You might want to try saving your image to .png, i.e. `myBitmap.Save("myFile.png", ImageFormat.Png)` to remove that possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately the formatting of the final image needs to be bmp. I'm exporting to bitmap both through photoshop and the above code.

Comment: .bmp is also uncompressed, so should be just fine. But `Image.Save` seem to default to jpeg compression, even if you specify ".bmp" as the file extension. So make sure you specify `ImageFormat.Bmp` explicitly.

Comment: Oops I misspoke. I'm handling the image as bmp in the code, but the saved format has to be jpeg and I was exporting to jpeg from photoshop also. Is there a way for me to specify the jpeg save quality in the code?

Currently saving like this:
`tempImage.Save(Properties.Settings.Default.lastPath + "\\icon.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: Then try saving the image as png/bmp to confirm that it is actually a compression issue and not a scaling issue. If that is actually the case, see [Set jpeg compression level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Exporting as PNG didn't cause the artifacts! I'll take a look at the jpeg link you sent, thanks for helping me narrow this down!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second image looks like it has fairly severe [jpeg artefacting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact). This is typically evident from a significant amount of noise near high contrast edges.

Photoshop likely also uses a more advanced downscaling filter, but the effect of this should only affect edges or other high frequency features, and the difference should be much more subtle than the large amount of noise in the example images.

See [How to set jpeg compression level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to control the amount of compression applied when saving images, and therefore the amount of noise:

```
        var jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
        var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);    
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);  
        myBitmap.Save(myFilePath, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Do note that different jpeg encoder libraries might produce slightly different result. The builtin encoder should be "good enough", but there are third party libraries that claim slightly better quality/file size. Also note that the jpeg format itself is really old, so if you are more concerned about quality/size than compatibility there are certainly better formats to chose from.

Comment: This was the cause of the issue. Using 100L I'm still not QUITE matching photoshop's exporting but it's close enough that I can't tell unless I zoom and look closely!